# how resolve FolioReader dependency problem

Tags: android, maven, gradle, build.gradle, jcenter

I try to use FolioReader library for use epub files in my project. I add dependencies to my project and build it but I get this errors:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 7 failures.
```

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
> Could not find com.github.codetoart:r2-shared-kotlin:1.0.4-2.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/codetoart/r2-shared-kotlin/1.0.4-2/r2-shared-kotlin-1.0.4-2.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/codetoart/r2-shared-kotlin/1.0.4-2/r2-shared-kotlin-1.0.4-2.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/codetoart/r2-shared-kotlin/1.0.4-2/r2-shared-kotlin-1.0.4-2.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > com.folioreader:folioreader:0.5.4
> Could not find com.github.codetoart:r2-streamer-kotlin:1.0.4-2.
> Searched in the following locations:
> - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/codetoart/r2-streamer-kotlin/1.0.4-2/r2-streamer-kotlin-1.0.4-2.pom
> - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/github/codetoart/r2-streamer-kotlin/1.0.4-2/r2-streamer-kotlin-1.0.4-2.pom
> - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/codetoart/r2-streamer-kotlin/1.0.4-2/r2-streamer-kotlin-1.0.4-2.pom
> Required by:
> project :app > com.folioreader:folioreader:0.5.4

build.gradle:

```
 repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
}
```

build.gradle(app):

```
 implementation "com.folioreader:folioreader:0.5.4"
implementation 'com.github.codetoart:r2-shared-kotlin:1.0.4-2'
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems this dependency, specifically the one with this group ID exists in Jitpack.io. You should simply add the jitpack.io to your gradle repositories.
See here: https://jitpack.io/p/codetoart/r2-shared-kotlin

Comment: I add dependency that you said but I get the same errors

Comment: @MohammadhoseinHosseini can you update the issue with the error you currently have? I checked the above two dependencies - they exist and can be downloaded from jitpack.io:
https://jitpack.io/com/github/codetoart/r2-shared-kotlin/1.0.4-2/r2-shared-kotlin-1.0.4-2.pom
https://jitpack.io/com/github/codetoart/r2-streamer-kotlin/1.0.4-2/r2-streamer-kotlin-1.0.4-2.pom

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android#gradle) on how to implement .

You need to have these repositories

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        ...
    }
}
```

and the following dependency

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation "com.folioreader:folioreader:0.5.4"
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks bro... I do it like you said and I get new errors and I search them and solve them (:

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and when going to [Jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io/#FolioReader/FolioReader-Android/0.5.4), they said to use:

```
implementation 'com.github.FolioReader:FolioReader-Android:0.5.4'
```